# Initializing UINavigationController in AppDelegate with IB rootViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working in my AppDelegate to make the app's view return to the first view every time it comes from the background.

First off, I have a navigation controller set up in IB as my initial view controller.
Despite this, if I put

```
if (!self.window.rootViewController.navigationController)
NSLog(@"null rootview navcontroller");
```

in appDidFinishLaunching the NSLog happens indicating that my window's navigation controller is null.
So, I figured I would try instantiating it myself with:

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
```

But when I try that I get error:

```
Pushing a navigation controller is not supported
```

Which I must confess I don't really understand.  I shouldn't be pushing anything?

Thanks!

Comment: If the navigation controller is the initial view controller then `self.window.rootViewController` should be the navigation controller itself. Did you check `self.window.rootViewController`?

Comment: Good call - this was the case.
I do think I typed this first but the typing warning threw me off.
But I cast it like so:     self.navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;

Comment: Good, I'll make that an answer for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the navigation controller is the initial view controller then `self.window.rootViewController` should be the navigation controller itself.

The type for `rootViewController` is UIViewController, so you will need to cast as needed.